# Configure spring redis cache for spring cloud aws?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, amazon-elasticache, spring-data-redis

I am new to using AWS and ElastiCache. According to the official [Spring Cloud AWS](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_caching) documentation, Spring Cloud has its own implementation of memcache, so if I want to use Redis, I'd need to add the dependencies for Redis. From there, Spring Cloud would automatically use this driver.

Do I need to add configuration for Redis, or will Spring Cloud only pick the driver and configure Redis on its own?

Comment: did you find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

you need to provide redis server and port in JedisConnectionFactory which needs to be configured in RedisTemplate and which should be bind with CacheManager bean in Spring configuration file.

```
public JedisConnectionFactory cacheJedisConnectionFactory() {

        String redisServerURL = environment.getProperty(
                CacheConstants.PROP_REDIS_HOST, String.class);
        int redisServerPort = environment.getProperty(
                CacheConstants.PROP_REDIS_PORT, Integer.class);

        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName(redisServerURL);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setPort(redisServerPort);
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }

public RedisTemplate cacheRedisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cacheJedisConnectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(new KryoObjectSerializer());
        return redisTemplate;
    }

public CacheManager distributedCacheManager() {

        XXXXXX..........
        DistributedCacheManager cacheManager = new DistributedCacheManager(
                cacheRedisTemplate());
        cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXX......
        return cacheManager;
    }
```